# Java store list to array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to read CSV file like this:

```
1,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,
0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,
```

This is my expected outcome:

```
[1, 5, 8]
[2, 8,]
[7]
```

This is my Java coding:

```
CSVReader a = new CSVReader(new FileReader("CM.csv"));
List<String[]> aa = a.readAll();

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
Object[] CM = new Object[3];

for (int i = 0; i < aa.size(); i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < aa.get(i).length-1; x++) {
        if ( Integer.parseInt(aa.get(i)[x].trim()) >= 1 ){
                list.add(x+1);
            }
        }            
        CM[i] = list;
        list.clear();
    }

for (int i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(CM[i]);
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

But I get Null outcome. If I delete the list.clear() line then get weird outcome like this :

```
[1, 5, 8, 2, 8, 7]
[1, 5, 8, 2, 8, 7]
[1, 5, 8, 2, 8, 7]
```

I want to store the list into the array, please ignore the way how i read the CSV file...

Comment: Two things: 1. How do you actually get to that output? 2. You should use better variable names than a and aa.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Re: BradyK
If i know i no need to ask here

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do so we can help you...u have the excel input now what do you want to do with the excel input?

Comment: I'm trying to create a list then store to the array CM then clear the list and reuse it again in the loop.

Comment: So you want to convert the list to an array?

Comment: Your input -> output makes no sense.  Why would a row that was `0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,` produce the outcome of `[7]`, or even `[1, 5, 8, 2, 8, 7]`.  Also, why does your CSV have an extra `,` at the end? Finally, variables should be somewhat descriptive of their purpose.  Calling you List `a` and your reader `aa` makes for VERY confusing-to-read code.  I can totally understand obviscating your code a bit so you are not giving away the horse, but you could make the List something like `contents` and the reader `csvReader`, and it would help a LOT.

Comment: Not convert but store..... and the aa.size() is the number of row of the CSV file aa.get(i).length is the number of integer of the current row i......

Comment: Store the arraylist in a multi-dimensional array because your input and output do not match that description?

Comment: @CodeChimp I think the second array indicates the index of non-zero values in the initial array.

Comment: @JGrice, Ah! That makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `list.clear();` with `list = new ArrayList<>();`

you are assigning list to CM[i] and when you are calling list.clear() it clears the list and makes it empty list, as your CM variable is referring to list object, it wont have any values in it.

To get the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
    List dataList = (List) CM[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < dataList.size(); j++) {
        // do your stuff
        System.out.println(dataList.get(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 more question, how can i access the list value of the each array CM?? if i use CM[i].list[j] it does't work

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
        List datalist = (List)CM[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < datalist.size(); j++) {
                    System.out.print(CM[i].get(i)[j]);
                }
            }

I do like this but can't......

Comment: I'm not prefer to create a new listdata. But can make it access to the CM[i] and list? like CM[i].list[i]

Comment: here you are not creating any new list object, you are just referring to the existing list object. in that case you can use System.out.print(CM[i].get(j)); with in second loop

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Location {
   private int x = 0;
   private int y = 0;

   public Location(int x, int y)
   {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }

   public int getX()
   {
       return this.x;
   }
   public int getY()
   {
       return this.y.
   }

}


CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("CM.csv"));
List<String[]> records = csvReader.readAll();

ArrayList<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

for(int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < records.get(i).length; j++)
    {
        if(Integer.parseInt(records.get(i)[j]) > 0)
        {
             locations.add(new Location(i,j));
        }
    }
}
```

Now all your locations will be stored in the locations arraylist.  All you have to do is loop through that and get your coordinates for the records arraylist.

Comment: My question is focus on how to store the list into the array, not shortcut my coding, pls ignore how i read the input

Comment: This is exactly how you store the list into an array.  This answers your question try the code.

Comment: read again my question, i have edited maybe u can see the diff

Comment: I've read it several times it makes no sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want to store the locations where the number is greater than 1 then just create a location class with x and y and store those objects in an arraylist.  Your question is very unclear as to what you are trying to do or why you are trying to do it.  Based on what you said in the comments this answer is correct.  You need to be more clear about what you are asking then we can better help you.

Comment: ya, exactly i want to store the location of which the number >= 1

Comment: sorry i have edited my question just now, u can see the diff again?

Comment: Look at this code and try it maybe what you want.  It is better than what you are doing now I think.  You will have one arraylist with all the actual data and the other arraylist will have the locations where the data > 0.

Comment: Don't hard code 3 as your array because potentially you don't know how many values are going to be greater than 0 in the row. Also you are making a multidimensional array and only using some of the slots this is inefficient you should use single arraylist like i showed in my example.